# SQL combine two tables with date interval

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, intervals, dateinterval

I have 2 tables with start and end dates.
I have to join then in a particular way:

Table A:

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 |
| 1 | 10/01/2024 | 15/01/2024 |
| 1 | 15/01/2024 | 20/01/2024 |
| 2 | 01/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 |
| 2 | 10/01/2024 | 20/01/2024 |

Table B:

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/01/2024 | 11/01/2024 |
| 1 | 12/01/2024 | 18/01/2024 |
| 2 | 10/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 |

Output:

| ID | Start Date (A) | End Date (A) | Start Date (B) | End Date (B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 10/01/2024 | 15/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 | 11/01/2024 |
| 1 | 10/01/2024 | 15/01/2024 | 12/01/2024 | 18/01/2024 |
| 1 | 15/01/2024 | 20/01/2024 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 10/01/2024 | 20/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 | 10/01/2024 |

Can you find the correct SQL query with `WHERE` condition to obtain the desired output? Without using `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Could you tag the RDBMS (sql server, oracle ...) You are using ?

Comment: i'm using snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using LEFT JOIN.

If there is no matching row in TableB, we still include the row from TableA with NULL values for StartDate_B and EndDate_B.

```
  SELECT 
    A.ID,
    A.StartDate AS StartDate_A,
    A.EndDate AS EndDate_A,
    B.StartDate AS StartDate_B,
    B.EndDate AS EndDate_B
FROM 
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
            AND (
                (B.StartDate >= A.StartDate AND B.StartDate < A.EndDate) OR
                (B.EndDate > A.StartDate AND B.EndDate <= A.EndDate) OR
                (B.StartDate <= A.StartDate AND B.EndDate >= A.EndDate)
            )
WHERE
    B.ID IS NOT NULL
    OR (B.ID IS NULL AND A.ID IS NOT NULL);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/_YYKgFCo

Comment: i just added a new case (ID = 2). with this query i have problems on it

Comment: Edited. For Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/_YYKgFCo